# My artifactID in pom.xml is not registering in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, spring-data

For some reason my pom.xml's artifacts are red. I tried refreshing maven, using another maven dependency directly from the files.

I tried using built-in maven and the maven wrapper, but for some reason Artifact ID still can't be read.

[This is what pom.xml looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLGUE.png)

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Eclipse, IntelliJ does not load maven changes when the file is saved.

You have to trigger it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Also, you can click the small button that pops up in the `pom.xml` editor when you change anything:

[image]

This will load maven changes and will download new added dependencies as well as remove the deleted ones.

Comment: I don't see the small button on the right.

Comment: You can make it auto-import if you want, just like Eclipse (the worst java editor in the world, btw, imeo). You get a choice in IntelliJ, which is useful if you're making large edits to your pom and don't want it building every few seconds.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer JDeveloper is worse than eclipse for java development

Comment: @MatheusCirillo -- I'll accept joint bottom. Completely impossible to work with in any professional capacity is the bottom rung and it would be hard to go any lower ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these dependencies actually exist in your local Maven repository and update repositories in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Repositories** settings.
[image]